# Using HTTPS with Citrus Simulator

Tags: java, citrus-framework

I am cureently evaluating Citrus Simulator for writing Mocks for Rest Services. It looks promising, but I couldn't find out how to use HTTPS instead of HTTP while trying to setup a REST Service. Nothing found in the user Manual as well. Does somebody already tried that succesfully?

Comment: First hit in Google brought me this: http://citrusframework.org/samples/https/
You *should* be able to do the same in the Simulator. But I have not really worked with the Simulator itself...

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the underlying product citrusframework delivered half the answer, thx to Korashen for the tipp.

The relevant change is to set the correct endpoint adapter. For others looking for a solution:

```
@Autowired
private SimulatorEndpointAdapter simulatorEndpointAdapter;

@Bean
public HttpServer buildSslServer() throws Exception {
    return CitrusEndpoints.http()
            .server()
            .port(8080)
            .endpointAdapter(simulatorEndpointAdapter)
            .connector(sslConnector())
            .autoStart(true)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public ServerConnector sslConnector() {
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(new Server(),
            new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory(), "http/1.1"),
            new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfiguration()));
    connector.setPort(securePort);
    return connector;
}

private HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration() {
    HttpConfiguration parent = new HttpConfiguration();
    parent.setSecureScheme("https");
    parent.setSecurePort(securePort);
    HttpConfiguration configuration = new HttpConfiguration(parent);
    configuration.setCustomizers(Collections.singletonList(new SecureRequestCustomizer()));
    return configuration;
}

private SslContextFactory sslContextFactory() {
    SslContextFactory contextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    contextFactory.setKeyStorePath(sslKeyStorePath);
    contextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("secret");
    return contextFactory;
}
```